# Python lib to return the adjectival form of a Country

Tags: python, geolocation

I'm looking for a Python library to return the adjectival form of a country. For example, given "Brazil" it would return "Brazilian", given "Greece" it would return "Greek".

If there's no lib like this available, I'll crawl thie wiki page below and make my own, I just don't want to replicate effort in case someone has already done that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectival_and_demonymic_forms_of_place_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be the natural language toolkit, http://www.nltk.org/.  One of their data modules called WordNet shows the approximate distance in meaning between words, for example.  Assuming it has countries and national adjectives, you could certainly use their api to find what you need.

Comment: Excellent, look forward to hearing how it turns out.  From what I've seen of their stuff, you're at least guaranteed to get something worthwhile out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The is no such lib. The question you are asking is data related and if there were a solution it would be programming language neutral database of names.

Comment: I also expect there's no lib created just for this purpose, but I think this data may be available in some geolocation lib I'm not aware of.

Comment: An example of such a database would be https://mledoze.github.io/countries/.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I coded my own library for that. It's available on github:

http://code.google.com/p/spojtweet/source/browse/country_demonyms.py